# ¿Cómo solucionar el siguiente message de error relacionado con fechas :Incompatible methods ("-.Date", "-.POSIXt")?

Tags: r, date

Soy nueva utilizando R, necesito calcular el tiempo entre dos fechas: Date_inclusion y date_point, para lo cual estoy haciendo lo siguiente.

```
        cancer$date_point <- as_date("1980 - 02 - 15")
        cancer$delai_recul_j <-(cancer$date_point-cancer$Date_inclusion)
```

pero obtengo el siguiente mensaje.

`Warning message: Incompatible methods ("-.Date", "-.POSIXt") for "-"`

Al principio pensé que era el formato de la fecha del Mac, pero no funcionó, no sé que hacer, ya que evidentemente con la columna que se crea no puedo trabajar.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es básicamente la operación de resta: `cancer$date_point-cancer$Date_inclusion`, tienes `date_point` que es del tipo `Date` y  `Date_inclusion`  que es del tipo `POSIXt` y como dice el Warning, ambas clases son incompatibles para la operación que estás intentando, aunque ambas clases técnicamente son algún tipo de fecha.

La prueba de concepto del warning, sería:

```
library(lubridate)

days(as_date("1980 - 02 - 15") - as.POSIXct('1981-02-05'))
[1] "-956808-06-20"
Warning message:
Métodos incompatibles ("-.Date", "-.POSIXt") para "-"
```

La solución, es convertir previamente el dato `POSIXt`:

```
as_date("1980 - 02 - 15") - as_date(as.POSIXct('1981-02-05'))
Time difference of -356 days
```

En tu ejemplo sería:

```
cancer$delai_recul_j <-(cancer$date_point-as_date(cancer$Date_inclusion))
```